# How do I write a "while" loop in SQL where it is taking the largest value and subtracting the second largest value and so on

Tags: while-loop, statistics, analytics

I have a data set with multiple different case numbers and each case number has 1 or more orders. I would like to take the order with the largest time value and subtract the second largest time value from it and the third largest time value from it, etc. for each case number. Here is an example:

| Case # | Part Name | Time Part Took to Arrive
| 10     | Part A    | 50 min
| 10     | Part B    | 10 min
| 10     | Part C    | 100 min

I would like the code to do 100 min - 50 min - 10 min and return 40 min for case 10
(each case has a different number of orders on it)

I have tried writing a while loop but not sure if this is the correct method.